# Prevent Android AlertDialog from closing when neutral button is pressed

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, dialog

I am using Xamarin and the V7 support library from Nuget.

I want to override the default `Dialog.Dismiss()` behaviour. I have tried this with no luck, the dialog closes when the neutral (refresh) button is pressed:

**update for clarity:** The behaviour I require is that `MyDialog` remains open after the neutral button is pressed. Currently, when the neutral button is pressed the `refreshMyDialogButton_Click` method fires and then `MyDialog` is automatically dismissed.

```
using AlertDialog = Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog;

....
protected AlertDialog MyDialog;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    var myDialogView = View.Inflate(this, Resource.Layout.myDialogView, null);
    MyDialog = createMyDialog(myDialogView);
    MyDialog.Show();
}

protected AlertDialog createMyDialog(View myDialogView)
{
    var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder
        .SetNegativeButton("back", delegate { MyDialog.Dismiss(); })
        .SetNeutralButton("refresh", (EventHandler<DialogClickEventArgs>)refreshMyDialogButton_Click)
        .SetPositiveButton(/**foo**/)
        .SetView(/**my custom view**/)
        .SetTitle(/**title**/)
        .SetMessage(/**message**/)
        ;
    return builder.Create();
}

private void refreshMyDialogButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /** start async tasks but don't close dialog **/
}
```

**update 2**

I added the following code to the `onCreate` method, but this resulted in a Null Reference Exception on `dialogNeutral`:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    var myDialogView = View.Inflate(this, Resource.Layout.myDialogView, null);
    MyDialog = createGathererDialog(myDialogView);
    var dialogNeutral = MyDialog.GetButton((int)DialogButtonType.Neutral);
    dialogNeutral.Click += refreshMyDialogButton_Click;
}

protected AlertDialog createMyDialog(View myDialogView)
{
    var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder
        .SetNegativeButton("back", delegate { MyDialog.Dismiss(); })
        .SetNeutralButton("refresh", (EventHandler<DialogClickEventArgs>)null)
        .SetPositiveButton(/**foo**/)
        .SetView(/**my custom view**/)
        .SetTitle(/**title**/)
        .SetMessage(/**message**/)
        ;
    return builder.Create();
}
```

Comment: What about using setCancelable(false) ?

Comment: To clarify - is your issue the fact that the dialog closes, then fires the event or does it close without firing it?

Comment: @EvilBeer thanks for your reply, I have updated my question for clarity

Comment: @NicolasCortell `setCancelable(false)` affects the use of the `back` key and touching outside the Dialog as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buttons must be instantiated as `null` and then accessed via `.GetButton()` after the `.Show()` method has been called.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late for this answer, but you can try this in your dialog class.

```
this.Dialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

and while accessing from outside,

```
dialogBox.Dialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```